# Select no me coge el valor correcto del TextField al modificarlo

Tags: java

Buenas a todos, tengo una ventana que sirve para elegir Artista y Album a través de dos JComboBox, y a la vez estos rellenan dos JTextField, el JTextField que uso para el nombre del Album lo uso para editarlo y darle el nombre nuevo, pero el problema es que al hacer click en Modificar aunque haya editado el JTextField me sigue cogiendo el valor previo.

Este es el código de la ventana:

```
public class VistaAlbumesBuscar extends JFrame implements ItemListener, ActionListener{

/**
 * Componentes de la ventana
 */
private Coordinador miCoordinador;
private JTextField campoTextoArtista, campoTextoAlbum;
private JLabel etiquetaArtista, etiquetaAlbum, etiquetaArtista2, etiquetaAlbum2, etiquetaCanciones;
private JSeparator separador;
private JButton botonModificar, botonEliminar, botonEliminar2, botonAdd;
private List listaCanciones;
private JComboBox elegirAlbum, elegirArtista;
private DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCombo;
private Generador miGenerador;

/**
 * Iniciamos la ventana
 */
public VistaAlbumesBuscar() {
    iniciarVentana();
}

/**
 * Contenido de la ventana.
 */
private void iniciarVentana() {

    /*Propiedades Frame*/
    setTitle("Albumes: Buscar");
    setBounds(100, 100, 353, 437);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    /*Etiqueta Artista*/
    etiquetaArtista = new JLabel("Artista:");
    etiquetaArtista.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaArtista.setBounds(10, 11, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaArtista);

    /*Etiqueta de Album*/
    etiquetaAlbum = new JLabel("Album:");
    etiquetaAlbum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaAlbum.setBounds(10, 36, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaAlbum);

    /*Separador*/
    separador = new JSeparator();
    separador.setBounds(0, 76, 337, 2);
    getContentPane().add(separador);

    /*Etiqueta Artista II*/
    etiquetaArtista2 = new JLabel("Artista:");
    etiquetaArtista2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaArtista2.setBounds(10, 89, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaArtista2);

    /*Campo texto Artista*/
    campoTextoArtista = new JTextField();
    campoTextoArtista.setBounds(62, 89, 231, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoArtista);
    campoTextoArtista.setColumns(10);
    campoTextoArtista.setEditable(false);

    /*Etiqueta Album II*/
    etiquetaAlbum2 = new JLabel("Album:");
    etiquetaAlbum2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaAlbum2.setBounds(10, 121, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaAlbum2);

    /*Campo texto Album*/
    campoTextoAlbum = new JTextField();
    campoTextoAlbum.setBounds(62, 120, 231, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoAlbum);
    campoTextoAlbum.setColumns(10);

    /*Boton Modificar*/
    botonModificar = new JButton("Modificar");
    botonModificar.setBounds(62, 151, 89, 23);
    botonModificar.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(botonModificar);

    /*Boton Eliminar*/
    botonEliminar = new JButton("Eliminar");
    botonEliminar.setBounds(161, 151, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonEliminar);

    /*Etiqueta Canciones*/
    etiquetaCanciones = new JLabel("Canciones:");
    etiquetaCanciones.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaCanciones.setBounds(10, 206, 76, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaCanciones);

    /*Lista de Canciones*/
    listaCanciones = new List();
    listaCanciones.setBounds(10, 226, 210, 163);
    getContentPane().add(listaCanciones);

    /*Boton Eliminar II*/
    botonEliminar2 = new JButton("Eliminar");
    botonEliminar2.setBounds(226, 366, 101, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonEliminar2);

    /*Boton Añadir*/
    botonAdd = new JButton("A\u00F1adir");
    botonAdd.setBounds(226, 332, 101, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonAdd);

    /*Combo Artista*/
    elegirArtista = new JComboBox();
    modeloCombo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    miGenerador=new Generador();
    elegirArtista.addItemListener(this);
    elegirArtista.setBounds(66, 10, 227, 20);
    getContentPane().add(elegirArtista);
    miGenerador.llenarComboArtistas(modeloCombo, elegirArtista);    

    /*Combo Albumes*/
    elegirAlbum = new JComboBox();
    elegirAlbum.setBounds(66, 35, 227, 20);
    elegirAlbum.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(elegirAlbum);  
}

public void setCoordinador(Coordinador miCoordinador){
    this.miCoordinador=miCoordinador;
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evento) {
    if(evento.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        if(elegirArtista.getSelectedIndex()>0){
            miGenerador.llenarComboAlbumes(modeloCombo, elegirAlbum, elegirArtista);
            campoTextoArtista.setText((String)elegirArtista.getSelectedItem());

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    campoTextoAlbum.setText((String)elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem());

    if(evento.getSource()==botonModificar){
        try{
            AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
            AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

            String nuevoNombreAlbum=campoTextoAlbum.getText();
            albumVO.setNombreAlbum(elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem().toString());
            albumDAO.modificarAlbum(albumVO, nuevoNombreAlbum); 
        }catch(Exception excepcion){
            excepcion.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Y este es el código del método que uso para Modificar el Album:

```
  public void modificarAlbum(AlbumVO albumVO, String nuevoNombreAlbum){

    Conexion conexion=new Conexion();
    ArtistaDAO artistaDAO=new ArtistaDAO();

    try{
        String consulta="update album set title=? where title=?";

        PreparedStatement sqlModificarAlbum=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consulta);
        sqlModificarAlbum.setString(1, nuevoNombreAlbum);
        sqlModificarAlbum.setString(2, albumVO.getNombreAlbum());

        int validar=sqlModificarAlbum.executeUpdate();
        if(validar>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha modificado correctamente","Información",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha modificado el Album","Información",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        sqlModificarAlbum.close();
        conexion.cerrarConexion();
    }catch(SQLException excepcion){
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error modificar el Album","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Espero que se me entienda el problema. Gracias.

**SOLUCION**

Al final he encontrado la solución, no tenía nada que ver con el Update, si no con el evento de los ComboBox para mostrar su información en los JTexField; simplemente en la clase `VistaAlbumesBuscar` dentro del metodo `actionPerformed` debía poner esto así:

```
 if(evento.getSource()==elegirAlbum){
        campoTextoAlbum.setText((String)elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem());
      }
```

De esta forma el JTexfield del Album no se cambiará si no pinchamos en el ComboBox, y de esta forma el Update coge el valor correcto para modificar el nombre.

Comment: Tienes algún mensaje de error al modificar el album?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que cuando haces la modificación nunca pasas la referencia del registro a modificar, le pasas dos parámetros :

```
sqlModificarAlbum.setString(1, nuevoNombreAlbum);
sqlModificarAlbum.setString(2, albumVO.getNombreAlbum());
```

Pero nunca le indicas que registro vas a modificar, te recomiendo que manejes un identificador, o almacenes el dato original y también lo pases como parámetro.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es cuando agregas a albumVO el nombre del album:

```
    String nuevoNombreAlbum=campoTextoAlbum.getText();

    //no estas tomando el valor del JTextField.
 albumVO.setNombreAlbum(elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

debes tomar el valor que tiene campoTextoAlbum no el JComboBox :

```
   String nuevoNombreAlbum=campoTextoAlbum.getText(); 
 albumVO.setNombreAlbum(nuevoNombreAlbum);
```

Comment: `albumVO.setNombreAlbum(elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem().toString());` lo uso para que en el metodo `modificarAlbum()` el ´artistaVO.getNombreAlbum()´ obtenga un valor, el cual debe ser el valor que da el ComboBox ya que es el que debe rellenar el `where title=?`; mientras que `nuevoNombreAlbum` debe tomar el valor del TextField ya que es el nombre nuevo que yo le doy para que rellene `set title=?` pero el problema es que al dar al botón Modificar el valor del TextField se vuelve al que da el ComboBox y por lo tanto el metodo `modificarAlbum()`  rellena el `set title=?` con un valor erroneo.